# Behind-Polygon rendered in front anomaly

Tags: 3d

I found a anomaly during software-development but I am unable to

1. Understand what is going wrong or what did this caused.
2. How to name that anomaly in a conversation with other developers (if there is a name for that anomaly).

[image]

Comment: Its called z-ordering. And in this case since the redering engine uses painters algorithm what is drawn last is on top. Switch to some other function like z buffering on the numerous order independent alpha blending strategies, or reorder for the painters algorithm (which may mean cutting geometry to pieces).

Comment: I'd avoid alpha blending altogether, if at all possible. Use alpha masking if you have to have alpha, otherwise just lose the alpha. It tends to be far worse if you have 2 alpha textures in the z-sort. One, you can get away with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Moved to an answer for now, until we can get another with a better technical explanation than I can manage.*</sup>

It's a z-axis, or z-sort rendering issue. The engine cannot determine which should be at the front.

It can depend on what you are rendering in, on what platform. I know it from a gaming platform I used to work support for, though I don't know enough technical detail about it to help. Depending on your underlying structure it may not be fixable.
It can be most apparent if you have alpha/transparency in your skinning textures. At its simplest, removing any alpha can be enough to fix it.

*From further comments*
I'd avoid alpha blending altogether, if at all possible. Use alpha masking if you have to have alpha, otherwise just lose the alpha. It tends to be far worse if you have 2 alpha textures in the z-sort. One, you can usually get away with.